# "?" help button triggers WM_HELP _and_ WM_LBUTTONUP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a Windows application that registers one CALLBACK procedure that handles WM_HELP messages for the dialog, and one CALLBACK procedure that handles WM_LBUTTONUP messages for a custom button.

Now, when the user clicks the "?" button, then clicks the custom button, the help opens up as expected (on mouse down), BUT if the help window is not occluding the button, a WM_LBUTTONUP message is triggered as well for the custom button (on mouse up). This causes the button to trigger when the user was only asking for help.

Is there any way to stop the WM_LBUTTONUP message from being sent if the button press is for help?

EDIT: The custom button is implemented using a STATIC control. I believe this is because it needs to have an image and no border. So, it does not send BN_CLICKED notifications. In fact, it does not seem to trigger WM_COMMAND in the parent at all.

Thanks

Comment: No, it does not. And I do not have the option of making it so.

Comment: If you aren't showing the help modal, how can you stop the user clicking on your window?

Comment: Well, the problem is the SAME mouse click that opens the help also presses the button. I would like the mouse click to be ignored when user is asking for help. It is okay if the user wants to click the button after the help opens.

Comment: You said clicks the "?" button, then clicks the custom button. Now you say it is the same mouse click. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, on the second click (on the custom button) - that click opens up the help AND clicks the button. I will edit the question to clarify this

Comment: I see where you may be confused. Clicking the "?" button makes the cursor turn into an arrow with a "?" next to it. Afterwards, if the user clicks on something in the window, a help dialog should pop up. Clicking the "?" button does not open help immediately.

Comment: You should be handling WM_COMMAND on the dialog for executing code in response to a button click. Look for a [BN_CLICKED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) notification code. WM_LBUTTONUP is wrong message for this, if you, f.i., click the client area and move the mouse on the button and lift the button, a button up message will be posted to the button. This shouldn't be interpreted as a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it by creating the custom button (static control) with the SS_NOTIFY style, then handling the STN_CLICKED notification in the WM_COMMAND message. (SS_NOTIFY causes WM_COMMAND to trigger in the parent when it is clicked.) This does not trigger when using the "?" button. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is normal.  Be sure to use the button's BN_CLICKED notification to see the difference.  Generated when the user clicks the button, not generated when the user uses the help cursor.  The button still sees the normal button up/down messages so that's not a good trigger to detect a click.  Extra bonus is that the button can now also be clicked with the keyboard (space bar).

A good class library takes care of these nasty little details.

Comment: This probably works, but turns out the custom button is implemented using a static control, which doesn't seem to send BN_CLICKED notifications. Sorry for the confusion! I will update the question again...

Comment: Well, you'll need to fix that custom control.  Hard to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to create **?** as a custom control with `BS_CHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE` style and capture the mouse. After that you will get all the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message to this custom control and then you can use WindowFromPoint to get the window where the WM_LBUTTONDOWN happened and can send a custom notification to the parent window. The parent window can then show a the tooltip or open the help doc or discard it.

The advantage is, you create the control only once and you can use it in multiple places.